# Why does UIButton alter subviews' positions?

Tags: ios, uibutton, subclass, subview

I add 2 label and 1 image to show at specific positions in a button.

If I don't reset positions inside layoutSubviews method, button breaks all those positions. (for example sticks the image to 0,0)

If I add a parent contentView for all the subviews and add contentView to button, it doesn't change anything either.. button breaks positions inside the contentView too.

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: Probably something to do with your autoresizing masks. What's wrong with overriding layoutSubviews? You should almost always override this in UIView subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not working you can go for the `custom view`.

1) Add custom `UIView`.

2) Add your `labels` and `images` on it

3) Add `TapGestureRecognizer` to the custom view.

This will give you button like functionality, and all images and labels will be at proper position.

**Hope this will help you.**